# Cannot return an org.w3c.dom.Document by web-service method

Tags: java, xml, web-services, apache-axis

I am trying to return an XML Document Object from a java axis2 web service. When I am trying to get the Document object on the client side, it gives me these exceptions.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mapping qname not fond for the package: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at com.turnkey.DataCollectorStub.getData(DataCollectorStub.java:194)
    at com.turnkey.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:28)
```

Can I not return the Document object from a webservice ??
This service does return the XML string though.

Below is the pseudo code for the method I am using

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
public Document getData(args)
    {
     String xmlSource = "/*XML string*/";
     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));
     return xmlDoc;
    }
```

BTW, this method works fine on the server side, But on the client side I cannot receive the Document object

Can anybody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way doesn't use `Document` as return value, because axis2 cannot find suitable import in schema. If you generate wsdl every time you should add import org.w3c.dom.Document to wsdl schema (it is a inconvenient solution). That's why the best way in my point of view return specific entity

```
 public Credit[] getCreditList(){
            Credit[] credits = null;
            try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document xmlDoc = documentBuilder.parse(XML_REAL_PATH);

                Element root = xmlDoc.getDocumentElement();

                List<Credit> creditsList = new ArrayList<>();

            NodeList creditNodes = root.getElementsByTagName(CREDIT);
            int countCreditNodes = creditNodes.getLength();

            for (int i = 0; i < countCreditNodes; i++) {
                Element creditElement = (Element) creditNodes.item(i);

                Credit credit = new Credit();

                Element child = (Element) creditElement.getElementsByTagName(OWNER).item(0);
                String owner = child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                credit.setOwner(owner);

                //...
                creditsList.add(credit);
            }
            credits = creditsList.toArray(new Credit[creditsList.size()]);

        } catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreditPayService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return credits;
}
```